# Flutter || Check condition inside ListView.builder and use the result outside

Tags: flutter, if-statement, flutter-listview

i'm quite new to flutter and i have some difficulties to understand some things.

I'm using Firebase to store data, and i have a ListView.builder that builds a ListView based on data retrieved from the database.
I want that while i'm building the ListTiles in the builder, when i check a condition, a variable outside turns true, so i can subsequently build two buttons (or not if the variable is false).
I'd like other ways to determine if i have to build the buttons too.

The fragment of code is this:

```
bool isFounder = false;
          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(
              name,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            trailing: Radio(
              value: id,
              groupValue: selectedGroup,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  box.write('groupChosen', id);
                  selectedGroup = id;
                });
              },
            ),
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: snapshot3.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index2) {
                    print(isFounder);
                    if (snapshot3.data!.docs[index2]['Role'] == 'founder' &&
                        snapshot3.data?.docs[index2]['Email'] == user?.email) {
                      isFounder = true;
                      print('yeah it\' s true');
                    }
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot3.data?.docs[index2]['Name']),
                      trailing:
                          (snapshot3.data!.docs[index2]['Role'] == 'founder')
                              ? const Icon(Icons.star)
                              : null,
                    );
                  }),
              (isFounder == true)
                  ? Row(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => widget.presenter.handleInvite(),
                            child: const Text('Invita')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () =>
                                widget.presenter.handleDeleteGroup(),
                            child: const Text('Elimina'))
                      ],
                    )
                  : const Row()
            ],
          );
```

There are some debug prints to check if enters into the if and it enters.
Basically happens that the variable stays false.

I maybe got why it happens, and it's because it comes first the builder, then when it have finished, turns the variable true, but it have already built everything.
But i have no idea how to resolve this.

I really don't want to make another API call to check that condition, i mean, it would be a lot more efficient doing there, i think.
But i'm open to anything.

Forgive me if you see some serious mistakes in the code, I've rewritten the code a lot to find a solution (and of course searched the web).

If you need the full code ask, i didn't want to add useless things for the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to use a StatefulWidget and wrap the code where you change isFounder within a setState call. Watch the video at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: I'm already using StatefulWidget (I only sent a fragment of code). A setState wouldn't works fine in this situation, i think. The problem happens in build method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the ListView.builder executes asynchronously, and by the time it finishes and updates the isFounder variable, the UI has already been built, so the buttons won't be shown.

To resolve this, you can use a FutureBuilder to handle the asynchronous task of fetching data from Firebase and then display the ExpansionTile with the appropriate buttons based on the result. Here's how you can modify your code to use FutureBuilder
try this and let me know if you solve it :
// This function fetches data from Firebase and returns a Future that completes with the data

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchDataFromFirebase() async {
  // Your code to fetch data from Firebase goes here
  // Return the list of DocumentSnapshot after fetching
}

FutureBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
  future: fetchDataFromFirebase(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show a loading indicator while data is being fetched
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    } else {
      // Data fetching is complete, build the ExpansionTile
      bool isFounder = false;
      for (int index2 = 0; index2 < snapshot.data!.length; index2++) {
        if (snapshot.data![index2]['Role'] == 'founder' &&
            snapshot.data![index2]['Email'] == user?.email) {
          isFounder = true;
          print('yeah it\'s true');
          break; // Break the loop early since we found a founder
        }
      }

      return ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(
          name,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        trailing: Radio(
          value: id,
          groupValue: selectedGroup,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              box.write('groupChosen', id);
              selectedGroup = id;
            });
          },
        ),
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index2) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data![index2]['Name']),
                trailing: (snapshot.data![index2]['Role'] == 'founder')
                    ? const Icon(Icons.star)
                    : null,
              );
            },
          ),
          (isFounder)
              ? Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => widget.presenter.handleInvite(),
                      child: const Text('Invita'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => widget.presenter.handleDeleteGroup(),
                      child: const Text('Elimina'),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : const Row(),
        ],
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Now it works! I was already using FutureBuilder but i haven't thought using that for. I previously commented that it didn't work as expected, but i committed and error (i had to modify the code that you provided because of course you didn't know the code i've written before and i got wrong a variable).

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that you got it working with FutureBuilder.